# Plot terminating early

Tags: plotting, peak-detection

I have a function `K3T[2][2 r0 l, g2, z, c, T, p]` that is acting weird when evaluated for different `p`:

```
Plot[With[{r0 = 0.02, l = 0.5, g2 = 0, z = 1, c = 1, d = 3, N = 2, 
   T = 1/100}, {Re@K3T[2][2 r0 l, g2, z, c, T, p], 
   Im@K3T[2][2 r0 l, g2, z, c, T, p]}], {p, 0, 10}, Evaluated -> True,
  PlotPoints -> 1000, AxesLabel -> {p, K3T}]
```

The plot shows an unexpected peak in the real part that becomes visible only when significantly increasing the number of sample points. Secondly, the graphs of both real and imaginary part suddenly stop around $p = 7$. Can someone explain what is going on?

[image]

### Definition

`K3T[2][2 r0 l, g2, z, c, T, p]` is defined as follows:

```
DK3T[m2_, g2_, z_, c_, T_, p_, 
   k_, L_] = 
  T ( Sum[w[[j]] Log[Exp[1/T Sqrt[p^2 + m[[j]]]] - 1], {j, 10}]);
K3T[0][m2_, g2_, z_, c_, T_, p_] = 
  k D[DK3T[m2, g2, z, c, T, p, 
      k, L], k] /. k -> 1;
K3T[j_Integer?Positive][m2_, g2_, z_, c_, T_, 
   p_] := Module[{msqr}, (-1)^j/
     j! D[K3T[0][msqr, g2, z, c, T, p], {msqr, 
       j}] /. msqr -> m2];
```

where

```
w = {1, 1, 1, 1, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, 2};
m = {a[1, 1][m2/k^2, g2/k^2, z, c] k^2, 
   a[1, 2][m2/k^2, g2/k^2, z, c] k^2, 
   a[2, 1][m2/k^2, g2/k^2, z, c] k^2, 
   a[2, 2][m2/k^2, g2/k^2, z, c] k^2, 1/c k^2, 
   a[1, 1][m2/L^2, g2/L^2, z, c] L^2, 
   a[1, 2][m2/L^2, g2/L^2, z, c] L^2, 
   a[2, 1][m2/L^2, g2/L^2, z, c] L^2, 
   a[2, 2][m2/L^2, g2/L^2, z, c] L^2, 1/c L^2};
```

### Auxiliary functions

Custom square root with branch cut on negative real axis

```
sqrt[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] := 
 Piecewise[{{I Sqrt[-x], Re[x] < 0 && Chop@N[y] >= 0}, {-I Sqrt[-x], 
    Re[x] < 0 && Chop@N[y] < 0}}, Sqrt[x]]

Derivative[1, 0][sqrt][x_, y_] = 1/(2 sqrt[x, y]);
Derivative[0, 1][sqrt][x_, y_] = 0;
```

Coefficients from partial fraction decomposition

```
a[1, 1][m2_, g2_, z_, c_] := 
  1/2 (1/c + m2/z - I g2/z) + 
   I sqrt[1/(c z) - 1/4 (1/c - m2/z + I g2/z)^2, -(1/c - m2/z)];
a[1, 2][m2_, g2_, z_, c_] := 
  1/2 (1/c + m2/z + I g2/z) - 
   I sqrt[1/(c z) - 1/4 (1/c - m2/z - I g2/z)^2, (1/c - m2/z)];
a[2, 1][m2_, g2_, z_, c_] := 
  1/2 (1/c + m2/z - I g2/z) - 
   I sqrt[1/(c z) - 1/4 (1/c - m2/z + I g2/z)^2, -(1/c - m2/z)];
a[2, 2][m2_, g2_, z_, c_] := 
  1/2 (1/c + m2/z + I g2/z) + 
   I sqrt[1/(c z) - 1/4 (1/c - m2/z - I g2/z)^2, (1/c - m2/z)];
```

Comment: suggest generating tables and using listplot. That way you can see exactly what p values are giving anomolous results  (guessing a precision issue)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `PlotRange->All`. This is what I get (MMA10.4, MMA11.1 Linux)

```
Plot[With[{r0 = 0.02, l = 0.5, g2 = 0, z = 1, c = 1, d = 3, N = 2, T = 1/100}, 
     {Re@K3T[2][2 r0 l, g2, z, c, T, p], Im@K3T[2][2 r0 l, g2, z, c, T, p]}], {p, 0, 10},
       Evaluated -> True, PlotPoints -> 1000, AxesLabel -> {p, K3T}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: I did try `PlotRange->All` before posting, still the graph stops around 7. Could you repeat the plot with `PlotPoints -> 10000` or `100000` and see if the unexpected peak shows up for you then?

Comment: I am getting the same thing. Could you check the values with `Table` within `{p, 0, 4, 0.1}`? Then we can know if it is a plotting problem or evaluation.  Also, try to create a list and see how `ListLinePlot` looks like.

Comment: Evaluating `With[{\[Rho]0 = 0.02, \[Lambda] = 0.5, \[Gamma]2 = 0, z = 1, c = 1, 
  d = 3, N = 2, T = 0.01}, 
 Chop@Table[{Re@\[ScriptCapitalK]3T[2][2 \[Rho]0 \[Lambda], \[Gamma]2,
       z, c, T, p], 
    Im@\[ScriptCapitalK]3T[2][2 \[Rho]0 \[Lambda], \[Gamma]2, z, c, T,
       p]} , {p, 0, 4, 0.1}]]` I get `{{0.957036, 0}, {0.947885, 0}, {0.919065, 0}, {0.867531, 
  0}, {0.791339, 0}, {0.692762, 0}, {0.579627, 0}, {0.463479, 
  0}, {0.355618, 0}, {0.263672, 0}, {0.190519, 0}, {0.13529, 
  0}, {0.0951246, 0}, ...`. All looks regular here. `ListLinePlot` too. But how does that help?

Comment: Interesting. Even with `{p, 0, 4, 0.0001}` the peak doesn't show up in `ListLinePlot`.

Comment: I think it is a graphics problem then (or maybe a bug !). BTW, which OS and MMA version you are using? If possible can you try this with a different installation?

Comment: I'm using MMA 11.0.1.0 on macOS 10.12.5. Downloading 11.1.1 right now but that will take some time. Do you think a reinstallation of the same version might help as well?

Comment: Can't say anything for sure. The only thing I can suggest in such cases is to get the data and plot with `ListLinePlot` or use some other plotting software. I am not sure if it is a software problem or graphics/driver problem.

Comment: Quick follow up: The peak indeed disappeared upon updating from  MMA 11.0.1 to 11.1.1. Perhaps there was something wrong with my installation or this was one of the bug fixes.